# Ancova in R - Why does the addition of a randomly distributed variable (dominant hand) to model make all the interactions non-significant

Tags: r, regression, interaction, ancova

After reading tens of articles on linear models I'm here with my first ever question, I'm having real trouble with my first ANCOVA model in which I'm trying to see how response time (divided into two groups by the median) to survey questions affect the answer given (on 1-5 scale). ANCOVA because I'm explaining a quantitative variable (response) by factors both quantitative (response time, age) and qualitative (gender). There is a small interaction between age and response time (labelled "quantile") as shown, which I think is dealt with by the use of `*` instead of `+` in the linear model.

[image: Regression by age]

My regressions for age and dominant hand (1=right handed 2= left)

[image: Regression for dominant hand 1=Right 2=Left]

Here's my code and output which I interpret as "quantile significantly effects MScore when accounting for age and gender". I can't understand why gender:age is significant but that's beside the point.

```
df <- lm(MScore ~ quantile * gender * age, data = temp)
Anova(df, type=3)

Response: MScore
                    Sum Sq    Df   F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)           2445     1 2555.2500 < 2.2e-16 ***
quantile                22     1   22.7141 1.884e-06 ***
gender                  31     1   32.2602 1.354e-08 ***
age                      6     1    5.9897  0.014392 *  
quantile:gender          0     1    0.0222  0.881600    
quantile:age             3     1    3.3468  0.067339 .  
gender:age              20     1   20.9022 4.842e-06 ***
quantile:gender:age      8     1    8.0736  0.004493 **
```

What is really confusing me is when I add "dominant hand" to the model, a variable which should have no effect as it doesn't explain any of the other variances, this happens (almost **no relationships** are significant).

**EDIT** I changed hand from numerical as suggested (1/2) to factor (Right/Left) and it makes sense again. Here's the updated model

```
    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                       4.099e+00  4.781e-02  85.747  < 2e-16 ***
quantileSlow Response            -3.832e-01  6.499e-02  -5.896 3.79e-09 ***
age                              -1.740e-02  1.382e-03 -12.590  < 2e-16 ***
genderFemale                     -5.531e-01  6.609e-02  -8.369  < 2e-16 ***
handleft                          2.523e-01  1.309e-01   1.927    0.054 .  
quantileSlow Response:age         1.046e-03  1.745e-03   0.599    0.549
```

**Thank you**

Comment: You say `hand` is coded 1/2. That might be a reason for problems, you need to declare hand a **factor** (something like `hand <- as.factor(hand)`, or recode as 0/1.  Then change the output in your post!

Comment: Well spotted thank you so much, will do!